# Convert SQL connection from Asp classic to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I would like to convert my web pages from Asp classic to Asp.net (VB), What should I do instead of this code?

conn.asp:

```
<%
    Dim conn,connstr
        connstr = "Provider=sqloledb; Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS ;Initial Catalog=My_DB ;User Id=sa;Password=12345"
        on error resume next
        set conn=server.createobject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
        conn.open connstr
            if err then
                err.clear
                set conn=nothing
                response.write "Connect Error!"
                response.End         
            End IF

    %>
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Provider=sqloledb; Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS ;Initial Catalog=My_DB ;User Id=sa;Password=12345"))
{
    connection.Open();
    // Do work here; connection closed on following line.
}
```

VB.NET

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection("Provider=sqloledb; Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS ;Initial Catalog=My_DB ;User Id=sa;Password=12345")
    connection.Open()
    // Do work here; connection closed on following line. 
End Using
```

Various connection strings can be found [here](http://connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: Im using VB.NET I did the code you gave me but it returns this error :
(Compiler Error Message: BC30689: This statement can not appear outside the body of a method or a lambda expression multiline)